# git not fully working with self-signed cert

Tags: ssl, gitlab

I use self-signed certificate to crypt.
after some work, the https is working for git, but the git@xxxxx way does not work. here's the output:

```
Cloning into 'test'...
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `block in connect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `connect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:744:in `start'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:56:in `get'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:17:in `allowed?'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:51:in `validate_access'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:21:in `exec'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell:16:in `<main>'
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

both ssh and http works fine before I start the self-signed cert thing, so now the ssh+ssl not working.
I'm using nginx, gitlab 5.3, followed the install instruction on gitlab website.

I did a check, too.

```
~> sudo -u git -H /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: FAILED. code: 301

Check directories and files: 
    /home/git/repositories: OK
    /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys: OK
```

I think the 301 might be this part in my nginx config:

```
server {
     listen         80;
     server_name    gitlab.MYDOMAIN.com;
     rewrite        ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

don't know if it's related or something
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ssh+ssl ?

But the two aren't related from the client's side perspective (unless you want to do some kind of [ssh tunneling through NGiNX](https://gist.github.com/fnando/1101211))

An ssh connection would talk to the ssh daemon (which doesn't need any certificate) and would require that the correct ssh public key has been registered to the server account `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (done by GitLab when a user register said public key in his/her profile page).

The `gitlab-shell/bin/check` error is another issue, again not related with ssh issue.
It is gitlab-shell which tries to contact locally gitlab through an https API.
Solve that locally, and *any* connection (https or ssh) from the client will succeed.

In particular, check [issues 3892](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3892), and see if you need to add a CA to the `.crt` file served by NGiNX.

[LJ Vankuiken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1761376/lj-vankuiken) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356972/git-not-fully-working-with-self-signed-cert/17357813#comment50395942_17357813):

> the self-signed flag needs to be set to "true" if the certificate chain presented by your gitlab server cannot be completely verified by the gitlab-shell.
>   I was able to set the self-signed flag to "false" by adding the signing authority's certificate to the system certificate store.

Comment: what do you mean by "add a CA to the .crt file"? I have an apache server running serving a crt that I signed by myself as a CA. (not self signed, I became my own CA.) and I'm unsure of what you mean by add a CA to the crt

Comment: @snowe2010 then your certificate is complete, since it is its own CA. I meant that, for a certificate to work, it needs to be validated by a CA.

Comment: @VonC So even though my certificate isn't self-signed (technically) do I still need to enable the self-signed flag in gitlab-shell?

Comment: @snowe2010 Not sure actually, since I have only worked with signed certificate (self-signed or validated by a CA)

Comment: @VonC well my certificate is signed. By itself. So it's a signed cert,  validated by a CA (which is itself)

Comment: @snowe2010 I would still set the self-signed certificate flag in gitlab-shell, to test it out.

Comment: @snowe2010 I have just tried this out and the self-signed flag needs to be set to "true" if the certificate chain presented by your gitlab server cannot be completely verified by the gitlab-shell.  I was able to set the self-signed flag to "false" by adding the signing authority's certificate to the system certificate store.

Answer (score 5):

The issue you're having is when you enabled ssl you also redirected http to https.

Accessing the old `http://` url works on most clients, but gitlab-shell (used as part of the login process on the gitlab server) will not follow 3xx redirects and instead return an error, thus disabling ssh-based access.

The fix is to edit `/home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml` and replace the `http://` in `gitlab_url:` with `https://`.

If you're using self-signed certificates, you may also have to set `self_signed_cert: true` under `http_settings:`

Answer (score 3):

for gitlab 6.0 this fixed the error for me: if using self signed certificates make sure that in gitlab-shell/config.yml your gitlab_url  is https://... rather than http://... and that you specify self_signed_cert: true

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth in case anyone gets similar, I am running Gitlab on port 8080 and because gitlab_url in gitlab-shell/config.yml was NOT pointing to port 8080 it was failing with a redirect error (which my server running on 80 was kicking up).

So to summarize, if you access gitlab via http://gitlab.mydomain.com:8080/ make sure gitlab_url points to http://gitlab.mydomain.com:8080/ as well!